# Calculate the directional derivative of $f(x,y)= \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} $ in the direction $\vec{v}=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)= \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} $ when $(x,y)\neq0$  and $f(x,y)=0$  when $(x,y)=0$

The question:
Calculate the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $\vec{v}=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ at point $(x,y)$ .

What I did:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f((x,y)+h(\cos\phi,\sin\phi))-f(x,y)}{h}$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h\cos\phi,y+\sin\phi)-f(x,y)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left({\frac{(x+h\cos\phi)^2-(y+h\sin\phi)^2}{(x+h\cos\phi)^2+(y+h\sin\phi)^2}-\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$

This seems right, but it seems that if I start multiplying everything, it becomes hell, and I can't get it right when there are three lines of equations.

Am I missing something? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You should be converting $(x,y)$ to polar coordinates first.

Comment: use computational formula for directional derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\cos \phi + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\sin \phi$

Comment: You have a $-$ where there should be a $+$ in the last equation.

Comment: Expressing everything in terms of polar coordinates (as @JoeJohnson126 mentioned) simplifies the computation, but not entirely. Still, the final result looks quite nice after using some simple trigonometrical tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directional derivative of the function $g(x, y)$, at the point $(x_0, y_0)$, in the direction of any vector $\vec w = (w_x, w_y)$ is the rate of change of $g(x, y)$ along the line

$l(t) = (x_0, y_0) + t\vec w = (x_0 + tw_x, y_0 + t w_y) \tag{1}$

is defined to be

$\dfrac{g(l(t))}{dt} \mid_{t = 0} = \dfrac{dg(x_0 + tw_x, y_0 + t w_y)}{dt} \mid_{t = 0}; \tag{2}$

if we apply the multi-variable chain rule to (2) we find

$\dfrac{dg(x_0 + tw_x, y_0 + t w_y)}{dt} \mid_{t = 0}$
$ = \dfrac{\partial g(x_0, y_0)}{\partial x} \dfrac{d(x_0 + tw_x)}{dt} + \dfrac{\partial g(x_0, y_0)}{\partial y} \dfrac{d(y_0 + tw_y)}{dt} = \nabla g(x_0, y_0) \cdot (w_x, w_y); \tag{3}$

thus,

$\dfrac{g(l(t))}{dt} \mid_{t = 0} = \nabla g(x_0, y_0) \cdot (w_x, w_y); \tag{4}$

taking

$g(x, y) = f(x, y) = \dfrac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = x^2(x^2 + y^2)^{-1} - y^2(x^2 + y^2)^{-1},  \tag{5}$

we find

$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 2x(x^2 + y^2)^{-1} - x^2(x^2 + y^2)^{-2}(2x) + y^2(x^2 + y^2)^{-2}(2x)$
$= 2x(x^2 + y^2)^{-1} - 2x^3(x^2 + y^2)^{-2} + 2xy^2(x^2 + y^2)^{-2}$
$= 2x(x^2 + y^2)(x^2 + y^2)^{-2} - 2x^3(x^2 + y^2)^{-2}+ 2xy^2(x^2 + y^2)^{-2} = \dfrac{4xy^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}; \tag{6}$

now we can really write down the $y$-derivative of $g$ by symmetry:

$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y} = -\dfrac{4x^2y}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}; \tag{7}$

we can now bring it all together using (4) with $\vec w = \vec v = (\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ to find the required directional derivative at any point $(x_0, y_0) \ne 0$:

$\dfrac{dg(l(t))}{dt} \mid_{t = 0} = \dfrac{4x_0y_0^2}{(x_0^2 + y_0^2)^2}\cos \phi - \dfrac{4x_0^2y_0}{(x_0^2 + y_0^2)^2} \sin \phi = \dfrac{4x_0y_0^2 \cos \phi - 4x_0^2y_0 \sin \phi}{(x_0^2 + y_0^2)^2}. \tag{8}$

Well, there it is, done in plain old-fashioned cartesian co-ordinates.  Just out of curiosity, let's write down $f(x, y)$ in plain old-fashioned polars:  note that

$\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \cos \theta, \tag{9}$

$\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \sin \theta, \tag{10}$

whence

$f(x, y) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1; \tag{11}$

since $f$ doesn't depend on $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, only the component of $\nabla f$ tangent to the circle of radius $r_0$ will be needed to calculate the directional derivatives of $f$ at the point $(r_0, \theta_0)$; this is in fact

$\dfrac{1}{r_0} \dfrac{\partial f(\theta_0)}{\partial \theta} = -\dfrac{4}{r_0}(\cos \theta_0)(\sin \theta_0); \tag{12}$

(12) must be multiplied by the component of $\vec v = (\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ tangent to the circle $r = r_0$ at $\theta_0$; this circle is obviously given parametrically by $(r_0 \cos \theta, r_0 \sin \theta)$; thus the tangent vector at $(r_0, \theta)$ is

$(r_0 \cos \theta, r_0 \sin \theta)'= (-r_0 \sin \theta, r_0 \cos \theta), \tag{13}$

and the unit tangent vector is thus $(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$; the component of $\vec v$ in the direction of this tangent vector is then

$(\cos \phi, \sin \phi) \cdot (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta) = (\cos \theta)(\sin \phi) - (\sin \theta)(\cos \phi); \tag{14}$

the requisite directional derivative at $(r_0, \theta_0)$ is thus given by

$\dfrac{1}{r_0} \dfrac{\partial f(\theta_0)}{\partial \theta}(\cos \phi, \sin \phi) \cdot (-\sin \theta_0, \cos \theta_0)$
$= -\dfrac{4}{r_0}(\cos \theta_0)(\sin \theta_0)((\cos \theta_0)(\sin \phi) - (\sin \theta_0)(\cos \phi))$
$= \dfrac{4}{r_0}((\cos \theta_0)(\sin^2 \theta_0)(\cos \phi) - (\cos^2 \theta_0)(\sin \theta_0)(\sin \phi)). \tag{15}$

We can check (15) against (8) by using (9), (10) evaluated at $x_0, y_0, \theta_0$ and recalling that $r_0 = \sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2}$:

$\dfrac{4}{r_0}((\cos \theta_0)(\sin^2 \theta_0)(\cos \phi) - (\cos^2 \theta_0)(\sin \theta_0)(\sin \phi))$
$= \dfrac{4}{r_0}(\dfrac{x_0}{r_0} \dfrac{y_0^2}{r_0^2}\cos \phi - \dfrac{x_0^2}{r_0^2}\dfrac{y_0}{r_0} \sin \phi) = \dfrac{4x_0y_0^2 \cos \phi - 4x_0^2y_0 \sin \phi}{r_0^4}$
$= \dfrac{4x_0y_0^2 \cos \phi - 4x_0^2y_0 \sin \phi}{(x_0^2 +y_0^2)^2}.\tag{16}$

We see the two ways of computing the directional derivative agree.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you are missing is that the function is not continuous at the origin. Using your polar coordinates with angle $\phi,$ for fixed $\phi$ the function is constant, no matter how close to the origin you get. On the $x$ axis $y=0$ (but not the origin) the function is $1.$ On the $y$ axis the function is $-1.$

The directional derivative apparatus should give nonsense if done properly; the exceptional directions would be $x=y$ and $x=-y,$ as you are told the function is defined to be zero at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

$$
D_{\vec{u}}f=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\vec{x}+h\vec{u})-f(\vec{x})}{h} = 
$$
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+hu_x, y+hu_y)-f(x,y+hu_y)}{h}+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x, y+hu_y)-f(x,y)}{h}=\lim_{u_xh\to0}\frac{f(x+hu_x, y+hu_y)-f(x,y+hu_y)}{hu_x}u_x+\lim_{u_yh\to0}\frac{f(x, y+hu_y)-f(x,y)}{u_yh}u_y=
$$
$$
\frac{\partial  f}{\partial x} u_x + \frac{\partial  f}{\partial y} u_y = \nabla f.\vec{u}
$$
$$
D_{\vec{u}}f= \nabla f.\vec{u} = \frac{2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cdot\cos\phi-\frac{2yx^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cdot\sin\phi
$$

Comment: $$\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}(y\cos\phi-x\sin\phi)
$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the function $f'_x(x,y)$ and $f'_y(x,y)$ are not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ . Isn't it problematic?

Comment: $$\frac{f(hu_x,hu_y)-0}{h}=\frac{1}{h}\cdot\frac{h^2(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)}{h^2}=\infty$$ the above solution, also reflects this for $(x,y)=(0,0)$